# " ! [NOTE] There are available updates to apply" - but no way to apply them via CLI?

Tags: cli

When using Joomla CLI to check for update, I run

```
php cli/joomla.php update:extensions:check
```

and get

```
! [NOTE] There are available updates to apply 
[ OK] Check complete.
```

I'd expect the CLI to also support actually applying such updates? But that functionality does not exist yet, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of options available to handle the extensions

```
 extension
  extension:discover              Discover extensions
  extension:discover:install      Install discovered extensions
  extension:discover:list         List discovered extensions
  extension:install               Install an extension from a URL or from a path
  extension:list                  List installed extensions
  extension:remove                Remove an extension

 core
  core:check-updates              Check for Joomla updates
  core:update                     Update Joomla
```

Comment: Hm none of those seemed related to update? Or will `extension:install` do that? We also might need to update core Joomla. Would be nice to be able to do that via CLI.

Comment: I have added the core options. Your original command was for the extensions and yes Install will do an update if that is what is in the manifest. However I think you are possibly referring to the option to download the update via the vendors update link.

Comment: Great! Another related question: After running `update:extensions:check`, it doesn't seem to list which extensions are available for update. By design or missing feature?

Comment: Missing by design I think. The code executed in the update:check of your first question is doing the same as pressing the 'Check For Updates' button in the Extension manager. It looks for extension with an update available and adds the extensions Id to the #__updates table. There is potential scope to request some additional functionality to be included as part of the existing commands.

Comment: Got it, thanks @Irata!